# Sending a tag value to NSMutableArray objectAtIndex returns null

Tags: ios, tags, nsmutablearray

I have a list of product details as objects in NSMutableArray and list of product images as a gallery, I need to load full image on click of thumbnail images. For that, I set tag and get a exact tag value on click of particular image. The problem is I can't get the array objects.I test with manual numbers, array returns objects perfectly. What i did wrong here?

Tag setting code:

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.sliderImages count]; index++) 
{ 
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init]; 
   imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 0, 100, scrollHeight);
   imageView.tag = index;
   Products *product = [self.sliderImages objectAtIndex:index];
   NSLog(@"product name %@",product.name);
   NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.imagePath];
}
```

Tap gesture recognizer method:

```
- (void) tapGesture:(id)sender 
{ 
    //handle Tap... 
    UIImageView *tmp = (UIImageView *)[sender view]; 
    int tm = (int)(tmp.tag); 
    NSLog(@"self.sliderImages%@",[self.sliderImages objectAtIndex:tm]);
    Products *product = [self.sliderImages objectAtIndex:tm];
    NSLog(@"product%@",product); 
    NSLog(@"product ges %@,, %@",product.name,product.imagePath);
    NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.imagePath];
    NSLog(@"full image path :: %@",imageUrl); 
    [self loadFullImage:tm];
}
```

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried

Comment: Please check mu code - (void) tapGesture:(id)sender
{
    //handle Tap...
    UIImageView *tmp = (UIImageView *)[sender view];
    int tm = (int)(tmp.tag);
    NSLog(@"self.sliderImages%@",[self.sliderImages objectAtIndex:tm]);
    Products *product = [self.sliderImages objectAtIndex:tm];
    NSLog(@"product%@",product);
    NSLog(@"product ges %@,, %@",product.name,product.imagePath);
    NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.imagePath];
    NSLog(@"full image path :: %@",imageUrl);
    [self loadFullImage:tm];
}

Comment: Please add tag setting code.

Comment: for(int index=0; index < [self.sliderImages count]; index++)
    {
        
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 0, 100, scrollHeight);
        imageView.tag = index;
        
        Products *product = [self.sliderImages objectAtIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"product name %@",product.name);
        NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.imagePath];

Comment: @user1591698 Please add your code in your question and format it. so others can read easily and can give and asap.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not getting nil in the tag? (int tm = (int)(tmp.tag))

How are you getting the clicks on the UIImageView? Are you using gesture recognizer?

If you are using gesture recognizer then try like this to receive the touch and tags for the same

- (void)touch:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am getting exact tag value and also am using gesture event. When i test with this code -(void)tapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer , same issue.

Comment: Actually, this line NSLog (@"product%@", product);  gives product object but when i access product.name it gives null.

Comment: I hope NSMutable does not return a object property but it holds objects. I changed the code  to 
    NSMutableArray * productList;
         productList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
            for (NSDictionary *productDict in products)
            {
                Products *product = [[Products alloc] init];
                product.name = [productDict valueForKey:@"name"];[productList addObject:product];
            }

Comment: NSLog(@"self.productList%lu",(unsigned long)productList.count); -> returns count
    Products *product = (Products *)[productList objectAtIndex:index]; -holds objects
    NSLog(@"details %@ %@ %@ %@",product,product.name,product.imagePath,product.brand); -doesnot returns object property.